# How to find a,b and c in terms of the semi perimeter (s) from this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have an equation: $(s-a)/4=(s-b)/3=(s-c)/2$ , from this I'm supposed to get a,b and c (the sides of a triangle) in terms of s.. 
If I substitute $s=(a+b+c)/2$ in the given system of equations I get three other equations : $a+3b-2c=0$ 
$2a+b-c$ and $4a-3b+c=0$ . But still I don't see any quick way to find a,b,c in terms of s. Is the only way to get the them in terms of s, to actually solve for a,b and c and then get them in terms of s?
 *by getting them in terms of s, I mean being able to write them as $a = (constant)*s$ etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\frac a b=\frac c d$ then $\frac a b=\frac c d=\frac {a+c} {b+d}$ and similarly for equality for three fractions. Hence $\frac {s-a} 4=\frac {s-b} 3=\frac {s-c} 2=\frac {s-a+s-b+s-c} {4+3+2}=\frac {3s-2s} 9$. Now you can get your expressions for $a,b,c$ easily.

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{align}
\tfrac14(s-a)=\tfrac13(s-b)=\tfrac12(s-c)&=k
\quad\text{for some }k\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}

Then we have a linear system of four equations in 
four variables

\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&4 \\
0&1&0&3\\
0&0&1&2\\
1&1&1&0
\end{matrix}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a\\b\\c\\k
\end{matrix}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
s\\s\\s\\2s
\end{matrix}
\right]
,
\end{align}

which can be easily solved with any standard method
and has a solution in terms of $s$:

\begin{align}
a &= \tfrac59\,s
,\quad
b = \tfrac23\,s
,\quad
c = \tfrac79\,s
,\quad
k = \tfrac19\,s
. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Kavi Rama Murthy's answer. Denote the fractions by $k$: 
$$(s-a)/4=(s-b)/3=(s-c)/2=k \Rightarrow \\
s-a=4k;\\
s-b=3k;\\
s-c=2k.$$
Add them to find $k$:
$$3s-2s=9k \Rightarrow k=\frac{s}{9}.$$
Hence:
$$s-a=\frac{4s}{9} \Rightarrow a=\frac{5s}{9};\\
s-b=\frac{3s}{9} \Rightarrow b=\frac{2s}{3};\\
s-c=\frac{2s}{9} \Rightarrow c=\frac{7s}{9}.$$